# S3 PPT/PPTX file being downloaded rather than displayed

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, iframe, powerpoint

I am attempting to present a PowerPoint (PPT) file that was previously uploaded and stored on AWS S3 storage onto a specific view, a Laravel blade file, as part of a learning management system.

However, when a user accesses the blade file, rather than displaying the PowerPoint slide within the blade file, it automatically initiates a download of the PowerPoint file.

This functionality functions correctly when the displayed content is in the form of a "PDF" file or an "embedded YouTube link," but it fails to work when the content being displayed is a "PPT/PPTX" file.

```
  @elseif($courseMaterial->sections[$course_section_index]->combination_of_lessons_and_assessments[$course_page]->content_type=='ppt')
                            <div class="pdfDisplayContainer">          
                                <iframe src="{{ env('IMG_URL') . '/' . $courseMaterial->sections[$course_section_index]->combination_of_lessons_and_assessments[$course_page]->upload_document }}"
                                    headers="Content-Disposition: inline"></iframe>
                            </div>
                        @endif
```

To add on, directly accessing the material by opening the URL of the stored ppt slide on S3 will also result in the "ppt/pptx" being downloaded into my computer rather than it being displayed on the browser